# Use of prototype for single instance functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For performance optimization I'm using a single JavaScript file to handle all the pages of the website I'm working on.
The basic structure I'm using is as followed:

```
(function($) {

    // Shared functions ...

    // A function for every page
    function Page1() {
    }
    Page1.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            //...
        },
        //more functions
    };

    // more pages

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#page1uniqueidentifier').length) {
            var page1 = new Page1();
            page1.init();
        }
        // more pages
    }
}) (jQuery);
```

I'm not an experienced JavaScript programmer so I've been searching a lot about best practices and different ways of structuring my code and I've ended up choosing this one but I'm not really sure about it and I have a few questions:

1. Is it worth it to use prototype if I'm never gonna have more than a single instance of a page? I think I understand how prototype works and that I'm not gaining any performance there. But I'm using it just as a best practice because in the case different instances would exist, these functions would be the same in every instance.
2. Is there a better way to structure the code?
3. Should I put the call of the init function inside the constructor and then only call new Page1()?

   ```
   function Page1() {
       this.init();
   }

   if ($('#page1uniqueidentifier').length) {
       new Page1();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> For performance optimization I'm using a single JavaScript file to
>   handle all the pages of the website I'm working on

That makes no sense.  You should separate code into files, and then run all your js files thru a [minimizer/concatenator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843871/javascript-and-css-minimizer) to package it up.

Anyway, to answer your questions,

1. if you are only going to have 1, then prototype won't buy you anything.  However, if you are going to use more than 1, would you go back and change it?  Plus, using prototype wont hurt you either, so you might as well do it for learning.
2. You should create the files that make sense according to the functionality implemented.  I would separate your object definition into its own file, for example, so when you look at that file, all you see is the code for that object.
3. If you have a constructor function, you don't really need init, do you?

Comment: Well thank your for your answer. About using a single file, that's not exactly how it is done because we have separate files for external scripts and for different modules. But we handle all the custom code with one file for each website module that can have several pages. 
Anyway, even if I separate the code in different files and concatenate it later, I should control that Page2 code is not executed in Page 1 right?
About the constructor function, as the initialization code is often quite extensive, I've put it inside prototype so it won't be duplicated for each instance.